# PHP create a temporary copied file

Tags: php, file, copy, temporary-files

I've had a quick look around and I cant seem to find a solution to my question.

I can find how to create a copied file using **copy()**

```
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

and I can see how to create a temp file:

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); // this removes the file
```

But I can seem to work out how to merge the two.

What I want to do is create a file, that is copied from another file but will only stay on the server for a few minutes (5)

Am I going in the wrong direction here? All pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Files created by `tmpfile()` will be deleted when the script terminates. Is that what you waht to happen? Or by _stay on the server for a few minutes (5)_ do you mean you want the file to exists for 5 mins after the script finishes

Comment: Ah no, Is there a way to get it to delete after say 5 mins?

Comment: Probably best to run a cron ever X minutes to check if the temp files are older than 5 minutes, then delete it?